# Display a list of all the users using wp_query?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is it possible to use `wp_query` to create a list of all the Wordpress users for a site and their data? If so, how?

I want to be able to list ALL the users (the site is open to new registrations) and all their details such as name, username etc as well as some custom meta's that I've added in the format:

```
function my_user_contactmethods($user_contactmethods) {

$user_contactmethods['Address'] = __('Address');
$user_contactmethods['Website'] = __('Website');
$user_contactmethods['Phone'] = __('Phone');
$user_contactmethods['Nationality'] = __('Nationality');
$user_contactmethods['Registering as'] = __('Registering as');
$user_contactmethods['Submit work'] = __('Submit work?');
$user_contactmethods['Attend'] = __('Attend?');
$user_contactmethods['Volunteer'] = __('Volunteer?');

// etc for each field you want to appear

return $user_contactmethods;

}
```

Or if there's another way to do it then I'm completely open.

Comment: why do you want to use wp_query? You can use `get_users` instead.

Comment: @ksg91 Ok, how would I get the custom meta?

Comment: I have not worked with user meta so far but codex says you can use `get_user_meta`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are okay with not using `wp_query` , you can use `get_users` and `get_user_meta` to retrieve list of all users and their custom data.

For example,

```
<?php
    $blog_id = 1; //blog id
    $str = 'blog_id='.$blog_id;
    $users = get_users($str);
    $list = array();
    $i=0;
    foreach ($users as $user) {
       $list[$i]['id']=$user->ID;
       $list[$i]['email']=$user->email;
       $list[$i]['custom-1']= get_user_meta( $$user->ID, 'custom-1', true );
       $i++;
    }

?>
```

You can retrieve the fields that you want. Or you can just add all data and attach your custom fields with them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the correct way of querying users is with `WP_User_Query`. Seems very similar to how WP_Query works besides the foreach loop:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    .
    .
    .
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->get_results() ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->get_results() as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
?>
```

[Here is the full documentation and list of properties available](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_user_query/)